# Startup Time Slower On PC Than On Laptop

Tags: windows-10, ssd, motherboard, bios

For a while I had an HP Omen now and it started up pretty fast: With an i7 7th Gen and M.2 NVMe it with "Fast Boot" enabled it was up and running in 3.5 seconds (Windows Task Manager "Last BIOS time").

Now I have a custom build PC which starts in about 20 seconds. While that isn't too long, I still wonder, where this difference comes from?

Both systems have good CPU (i7 7th Gen/ Ryzen 7 3700X) and both start Windows 10 from an M.2 NVMe SSD with pretty similar read/ write values. Same amount of memory and power draw is similar too. Mainboard of the new PC is a Gigabyte Aorus Ultra Gaming X470, could this be a factory issue?

Where does this come from and can I fix this?

> What I tried so far:
>
> - Update BIOS (latest version)
> - Firmware of SSD and all other components updated
> - Chipset driver installed

Comment: As a "customed build PC" can have multiple new hardware installed with each reboot, the BIOS has to check for all these devices. As this is rather limited on a laptop, this could be an issue. But please be more specific: Which part is eating up the time? After power-on until BIOS-Screen? BIOS-Screen to Windows-Sandclock (Win10: the balls)? Or the loading after the login?

Comment: After power-on until BIOS-Screen. I am using the same hardware every reboot, it's just not built by some manufacturer, but by me.

Answer (score 0):

When you're waiting after power-on until the BIOS-Screen, the computer is still initializing equipment. This happens every time, whether you've changed your hardware or not. In the former times, you could audibly hear the floppy disk drive seeking, the CD-ROM-Drives spinning up etc. even before the BIOS-Screen.

The only chance you might have is finding the blocking equipment, so remove parts from the setup until it is faster. For example, there are hard drives out there which take a LOT of time to start.

Other than that - check if there's a "quick boot" option in the BIOS. If all else fails, you just have to accept that a standalone, custom-build computer with this specific hardware (especially motherboard).

There are quite a few ideas out there by other people, like checking where the DIMMs to be put or which options to try (e.g. reset to defaults by removing the CMOS-Battery for a few minutes and then replacing it).

Example:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/8ko13p/x470ryzen_2700x_slow_postbios_boot/

Comment: You are probably right: I just saw that there are indicators after boot which component is loading and it takes a lot of time at the DRAM state. Maybe there is a problem with my memory!

Comment: With one memory module it starts faster, but this isn't really working for me...

Comment: I sent back the memory, my reseller tested it but they found nothing. So probably not the memory.